# How to extract items line by line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need some help here using beautifulsoup4 to extract data from my inventory webpage.

The webpage was written in the following format: name of the item, followed by a table listing the multiple rows of details for that particular inventory.

I am interested in getting the item name, actual qty and expiry date.

How do I go about doing it given such HTML structure (see appended)?

```
            <div style="font-weight: bold">Item X</div>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-striped report-table" style="width: 800px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>Supplier</th>
                            <th>Packing</th>
                            <th>Default Qty</th>
                            <th>Expensive</th>
                            <th>Reorder Point</th>
                            <th>Actual Qty</th>
                            <th>Expiry Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>Company 1</td>
                                <td>3.8 L</td>
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    No
                                </td>
                                <td>2130.00</td>
                                <td>350.00</td>
                                <td>31-05-2019</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Company 1</td>
                                <td>3.8 L</td>
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    No
                                </td>
                                <td>2130.00</td>
                                <td>15200.00</td>
                                <td>31-05-2019</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>Company 1</td>
                                <td>3.8 L</td>
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    No
                                </td>
                                <td>2130.00</td>
                                <td>210.00</td>
                                <td>31-05-2019</td>
                            </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>Total Qty&nbsp;15760.00</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>



            <div style="font-weight: bold">Item Y</div>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-striped report-table" style="width: 800px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>Supplier</th>
                            <th>Packing</th>
                            <th>Default Qty</th>
                            <th>Expensive</th>
                            <th>Reorder Point</th>
                            <th>Actual Qty</th>
                            <th>Expiry Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>Company 2</td>
                                <td>50X10&#39;s</td>
                                <td>
                                    10
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Yes
                                </td>
                                <td>1090.00</td>
                                <td>271.00</td>
                                <td>31-01-2020</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Company 2</td>
                                <td>50X10&#39;s</td>
                                <td>
                                    10
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Yes
                                </td>
                                <td>1090.00</td>
                                <td>500.00</td>
                                <td>31-01-2020</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>Company 2</td>
                                <td>50X10&#39;s</td>
                                <td>
                                    10
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Yes
                                </td>
                                <td>1090.00</td>
                                <td>69.00</td>
                                <td>31-01-2020</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>Company 2</td>
                                <td>50X10&#39;s</td>
                                <td>
                                    10
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Yes
                                </td>
                                <td>1090.00</td>
                                <td>475.00</td>
                                <td>01-01-2020</td>
                            </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>Total Qty&nbsp;1315.00</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: ok you want to print any words of page line by line ?

Comment: i tried to use find_all and next_sibling but it doesnt work.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: i would like to extract the item name, actual qty and date and display in the following format (and i have written the export to csv portion of the script, what i need know is how to extract the info out using beautifulsoup)


thanks!

Comment: i would like to display them using the following format.

|S/N| Item  | Supplier      | Acutal Qty | Expiry Date |
|1. | Item X | Company 1 | 350.00     | 31-05-2019  |
|2. | Item X | Company 1 | 15200.00 | 31-05-2019  |
|3. | Item X | Company 1 | 210.00     | 31-05-2019  |
|1. | Item Y | Company 2 | 271.00     | 31-01-2020  |
|2. | Item Y | Company 2 | 500.00     | 31-01-2020  |
|3. | Item Y | Company 2 | 69.00       | 31-01-2020  |
|4. | Item Y | Company 2 | 475.00     | 01-01-2020  |

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to iterate through each row tag i.e. `<tr>` and then just figure out what the column cell at each index represents and access columns that way. To do so, you can use the `find_all` method in BeautifulSoup, which will return a list of all elements with the tag given.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = YOUR HTML HERE
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.find_all("tr"):
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 0:
        #This is the header row
    else:
        #If you want to access the text of the Default Quantity column for example
        default_qty = cells[3].text
```

Note that in the case that the `tr` tag is actually the header row, then there will not be `td` tags (there will only be `th` tags), so in this case `len(cells)==0`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. The idea is to iterate over the items - `div` elements with `bold` substring inside the `style` attribute. Then, for every item, get the next `table` sibling using [`find_next_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and parse the row data into a dictionary for convenient access by a header name:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """your HTML here"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
for item in soup.select("div[style*=bold]"):
    item_name = item.get_text()
    table = item.find_next_sibling("table")

    headers = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in table('th')]
    for row in table('tr')[1:-1]:
        row_data = dict(zip(headers, [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row('td')]))

        print(item_name, row_data['Actual Qty'], row_data['Expiry Date'])
    print("-----")
```

Prints:

```
Item X 350.00 31-05-2019
Item X 15200.00 31-05-2019
Item X 210.00 31-05-2019
-----
Item Y 271.00 31-01-2020
Item Y 500.00 31-01-2020
Item Y 69.00 31-01-2020
Item Y 475.00 01-01-2020
-----
```

Comment: many thanks for your help.

i tried the above code for following came out:

File "C:\grab\withoutlogin.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(item_name, row_data['Actual Qty'], row_data['Expiry Date'])
KeyError: 'Actual Qty'

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `divs` and walk through to find the next `table`.

If you go over the rows of the table with the exception of the last row, you can extract text from specific cells and build your inventory list.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")

inventory = []

for itemdiv in soup.select('div'):
    table = itemdiv.find_next('table')
    for supply_row in table.tbody.select('tr')[:-1]:
        sn, supplier, _, actual_qty, _, _, _, exp =  supply_row.select('td')

        item = map(lambda node: node.text.strip(), [sn, supplier, actual_qty, exp])
        item[1:1] = [itemdiv.text]
        inventory.append(item)

print(inventory)
```

You can use the csv library to write the inventory like so:

```
import csv

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,  delimiter="|")
    writer.writerow(('S/N', 'Item', 'Supplier', 'Actual Qty', 'Expiry Date'))
    writer.writerows(inventory)
```